# NodeJS Error in if else case - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I know, this is something old. There are many questions regarding to this. But none of them didn't guide me or didn't gave me the actual concept. 
My case is:

```
     if something
       render something
     else
       render somethingAnother
```

Why is this logic generates this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBtUx.png)

After 1st execution, I'm not able to continue this process (I could continue for a while, but after some time error will come), by pressing back button of browser and then returning back to the home page. Everytime I should restart my server using node command. Why headers won't reset if I press back button of browser, how to do some header reset or something which will correct my logic.

```
    const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');
    var async = require('async');
    var OrderID;
    var OrderNo;
    var compare = 0;
    var CompanyName;
    var notSimilar = 0;
    const download = require('image-downloader')
    const distanceThreshold = 30;
    var url;
    var FolderPath;
    var isSimilar = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var image1;
    var dbPath;
    var filterCount = 0;
    var image2;
    var dbImgCount = 0;
    var express = require('express');
    var request = require('request');
    var app = express();
    app.set('view engine', 'pug')
    var multer = require('multer');

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
      callback(null, './');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
   }
  });

  var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

  const sql = require("mssql");


 var config = {
user: '***',
password: '****',
server: '192.168.5.100\\SQLEXPRESS', 
database: 'Test_MatdesignDB1',
connectionTimeout: 300000,
requestTimeout: 300000,
pool: {
    idleTimeoutMillis: 300000,
    max: 100
   }
  };


 sql.connect(config).then(pool => { 
        return pool.request()
      .query('select count(*) from OrderImageUpload; select FolderPath from OrderImageUpload;')
  }).then(result => {
var a = JSON.stringify(result.recordset[0]);
        dbImgCount = a.slice(4,6);
FolderPath = result.recordsets[1];
sql.close();
 }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
    sql.close();
   })


    app.get('/',function(req,res){

        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");


    });

  app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
compare = 1;
upload(req,res,function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send("File uploading error");
    }
    else{
     // console.log("Success");
      image1 = req.file.filename;


      var matchFeatures = ({ url, img1, img2, detector, matchFunc }) => {

        // detect keypoints
        const keyPoints1 = detector.detect(img1);
        const keyPoints2 = detector.detect(img2);


        // compute feature descriptors
        const descriptors1 = detector.compute(img1, keyPoints1);
        const descriptors2 = detector.compute(img2, keyPoints2);

        // match the feature descriptors
        const matches = matchFunc(descriptors1, descriptors2);

       // only keep good matches
        const bestN = 40;
        const bestMatches = matches.sort(
          (match1, match2) => (match1.distance - match2.distance)
          ).slice(0, bestN);

        //console.log(bestMatches);


        for(var i=0; i<bestN; i++){

          if((bestMatches[i].distance) <= (distanceThreshold)){
            filterCount++;

          }
        }
        if(filterCount >= (bestN/4))
           isSimilar = 1;
        if(isSimilar){
          notSimilar = 0;
          filterCount = 0;
          isSimilar = 0;
          console.log("Similar images\n");
          dbPath = url;
          sql.close();
          (async function() {
            try {
              let pool = await sql.connect(config)
              let result1 = await pool.request()
              .query("select OrderID from Test_MatdesignDB1.dbo.OrderImageUpload where FolderPath = '"+dbPath+"';")
              OrderID = result1.recordset[0].OrderID;

              let result2 = await pool.request()
              .query('select OrderNo , CompanyName from Test_MatdesignDB1.dbo.[Order] where OrderID = '+OrderID);

              OrderNo = result2.recordset[0].OrderNo;
              CompanyName = result2.recordset[0].CompanyName;
              res.render('similar', { title: 'Similar', CompanyName: CompanyName, OrderID: OrderID, OrderNo: OrderNo, img_path_var : dbPath }) //Render number 1 in 'if' case
              } catch (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  sql.close();
                }
              sql.close();
          })()

          sql.on('error', err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
          }
          else{
            isSimilar = 0;
            filterCount = 0;
            notSimilar++;
            if(notSimilar >= (dbImgCount ))
            {
              notSimilar = 0;
              res.render('notSimilar', { title: 'Not Similar', message: 'No Similar Images' }) //Render number 2 in 'else' case
            }
            console.log("Not similar\n");
          }


        return cv.drawMatches(
            img1,
            img2,
            keyPoints1,
            keyPoints2,
            bestMatches
        );
      };


      for (j=0; j<dbImgCount; j++) {

        (function(j) {
          async.waterfall([
            async function downloadIMG(done) {
              try {
                  var options = {
                    url:  FolderPath[j].FolderPath,
                    dest: '/home/ubuntu/imgCompare/DBimages/'                
                    }
                  const { filename, image } =  await download.image(options);
                  return [filename, options.url];

                  } catch (e) {
                      console.error(e)
                  }


            },
            async function featureMatching([a, MatchURL], done){
              const img1 = cv.imread(image1);
              url = MatchURL;;
              const img = a.slice(33);
              const img2 = cv.imread('./DBimages/'+img);

              const orbMatchesImg = matchFeatures({
                url,
                img1,
                img2,
                detector: new cv.ORBDetector(),
                matchFunc: cv.matchBruteForceHamming
              });

              done(null);
            }


          ],
        function (err) {});
        })(j);
      }
      }
     });
    });


    app.listen(5000,function(){
       console.log("Working on port 5000");
  });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return before rendering a view. It's happening because the view rendering is happening more than 1 time there must be a condition in your code which is letting views to render multiple times. Add this return statement:

```
return res.render();
```

Comment: return res.render('similar', { title: 'Similar', CompanyName: CompanyName, OrderID: OrderID, OrderNo: OrderNo, img_path_var : dbPath })

                    
          return res.render('notSimilar', { title: 'Not Similar', message: 'No Similar Images' })

added return to both commands, won't working.

Comment: Everywhere? Couldn't understand!

Comment: Add return statement wherever you find res.

Comment: TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined. @Zeeshan this is the error after applying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're calling `matchFeatures()` multiple times within a `for` loop.

```
app.post('/api/photo', function (req, res) {
  var matchFeatures = ({url, img1, img2, detector, matchFunc}) => {
    if (isSimilar) {
      res.render('similar', {
        title: 'Similar',
        ...
      }) //Render number 1 in 'if' case
    } else {
      res.render('notSimilar', {
        title: 'Not Similar',
        message: 'No Similar Images'
      }) //Render number 2 in 'else' case
    }
  };

  for (j = 0; j < dbImgCount; j++) {
    async function featureMatching() {
      const orbMatchesImg = matchFeatures({ // since you're calling it multiple times here
        url,                                  // matchFeatures() will attempt to send
        img1,                                // responses multiple times
        img2,
        detector: new cv.ORBDetector(),
        matchFunc: cv.matchBruteForceHamming
      });
    }
  }
});
```

To fix this, You need to consolidate all these responses and send to client only once.

Comment: But I'm sending the response in        `matchFeatures()`      only once after the validation happens in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error. I didn't reset the variable      `notSimilar`      at the entry point.

Done resetting of `notSimilar` as below, no error! Thanks Everyone.

```
     app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){
          notSimilar = 0;
```